# how can i fetch array with vue.js using v-for

Tags: vue.js

HI am trying to print view with vue.js 
this is my script:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.cases" :key="index" >
<b>{{ siteObject.cases[index].id_number }}</b>{{  siteObject.cases[index].child_cases }}
</div>
```

with this script i have this result:

```
C34843161[ { "objid": 307273241, "title": "Release 17.4 // Testing // NOP TT", "s_title": "RELEASE 17.4 // TESTING // NOP TT", "id_number": "C34843164"}]
```

i wanna show add  the **id_number**

this part `{{ siteObject.cases[index].id_number }}` show  **C34843161**
and this part `{{ siteObject.cases[index].id_number }}` show this:

```
<br>
[ { "objid": 307273241, "title": "Release 17.4 // Testing // NOP TT", "s_title": "RELEASE 17.4 // TESTING // NOP TT", "id_number": "C34843164"}] <br>
```

and am talking about `id_number` for this part

Comment: Why are you using siteObject.cases[index] instead of item and what do you expect to be printed ?

Comment: @ZaidRehman i have no reason i have change it now to item i still have same problem

Comment: what you want to render after C34843161 ?

Comment: @ZaidRehman C34843164

Comment: All I read is *this part*. You might want to put a little more effort in clearly describing your problem.

Comment: @connexo i wanna make show the id_number C34843164 after that we can found hier [ { "objid": 307273241, "title": "Release 17.4 // Testing // NOP TT", "s_title": "RELEASE 17.4 // TESTING // NOP TT", "id_number": "C34843164"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.cases" :key="index" >
   <b>{{ item.id_number }}</b>
   {{ item.child_cases.length == 0 ? "" : item.child_cases[0].id_number }}
</div>
```

Comment: i have no result only the first one this part {{ siteObject.cases[index].id_number }} and this part {{  siteObject.cases[index].child_cases.id_number }} nothing

Comment: <div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.cases" :key="index" >
<b>{{ item.id_number }}</b>{{ item.child_cases.id_number }}
</div>

Comment: ok now i have error app.js:1678 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_number' of undefined"

Comment: that's because you have some empty arrays for child_cases, check updated answer

Comment: Thanks you save my day :-)